# Why do I get an error on one specific PC when I try to use Office on Demand on it?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, office365, office-on-demand

I have an Office 365 subscription. Whenever I attempt to run any Office on Demand application on my computer, I receive an error that there was an error trying to validate my Office 365 subscription (it does not tell me what the specific error is; it just states that there was an error) and that the Office application needs to close. When I do the same on other PCs, I do not receive the same error. What could cause it? (Could it be that I have used one of my Office installs on the other OS on my PC?)

Comment: Yes it could be as you say if you are only allowed to be using it in one location at a time. You'd have to check your licensing agreement.